# Identify an opend Webbrowser with ShellExecute properly to work with document.getElement

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, browser

I need to automation my job by filing Forms in webpage by js,I made a code like this:

```
var ie = new ActiveXObject("InternetExplorer.Application");

ie.visible = true;

ie.navigate("http://www.google.com");

while (ie.busy) WScript.Sleep(100);


ie.document.getElementsByName('q')[0].value ="3";


var Butn = ie.document.getElementsByName('btnK')[0];

 Butn.click();
```

but I want this code work with another web browser (e.g.Firefox) so I tried something like this:

```
var ie = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
 
var commandtoRun ="C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe";

ie.ShellExecute(commandtoRun,"http://www.google.com", "1");


while (ie.busy) WScript.Sleep(100);


 ie.document.getElementsByName('q')[0].value ="3";


var Butn = ie.document.getElementsByName('btnK')[0];

 Butn.click();
```

but this code throw an error:

**'ie.document' is null or not an object**

**800A13F**

I ask for any of these tow  ways:

*dealing with a web browser already opened not only open one then applying the code.

*Identify the opened web browser in proper way to apply the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that you are using an ActiveX object that is only supported by the IE browser.

This object is a Microsoft extension and is supported in Internet Explorer only.

If you are looking to automate the other browsers like Firefox, I suggest try to check [Selenium web driver](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/). I think that it is more suitable product to fulfill your requirements.

It is available to automate the browsers using many developing languages.

It looks like it is also possible to get an object of already opened browser.

See here: [Can we use Selenium to work with an already open browser session?](https://www.edureka.co/community/2170/can-we-use-selenium-to-work-with-already-open-browser-session)

Comment: Thank you @Deepak-MSFT, the first part of code works perfectly it opens the browser whatever its type, the problem was with getelement only, is there way to dealing with browser after opening? Or is there a different way to identify the browser instead of  ActiveXobject?

Comment: Even if you mange to launch the browser, it will not return the object model to access the elements on the page. I think that Selenium web driver can serve the purpose for this requirement. You can try to check it.